# Splitting numpy array into different parts and summing each part rowwise

Tags: numpy

I have a list of arrays say

```
k=[array([0, 2], dtype=int64),
array([1], dtype=int64),
array([3, 4], dtype=int64)]
```

There is also an array

```
e=array([[0., 4., 0., 0.],
         [1., 2., 2., 0.],
         [0., 0., 2., 4.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 3.]])
```

I want to get an array x as follows

```
array([[0,4,2,4],
       [1,2,2,0],
       [0,0,0,3]])
```

Here

```
 x[0] = e[0]+e[2]
 x[1] = e[1]
 x[2] = e[3]+e[4]
```

I want this in a vectorized fashion(without loops).Is this possible?

Comment: Owing to the ragged nature, it's not possible, unless you make a regular array from the list of arrays.

Comment: You will have to explain yourself better. What has `k` to do with anything for instance?

Comment: Each element in k, which is an array is the indices of e that i want to add

Answer (score 0):

If the input arrays are all the same size, a full numpy solution is possible:

```
k = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 1], [3, 4]], dtype=int)

e = np.array([[0., 4., 0., 0.],
         [1., 2., 2., 0.],
         [0., 0., 2., 4.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 3.]])

e[k].sum(axis=1)
```

If not, using a loop is I think necessary:

```
import numpy as np

k = [np.array([0, 2], dtype=int),
     np.array([1], dtype=int),
     np.array([3, 4], dtype=int)]

e = np.array([[0., 4., 0., 0.],
         [1., 2., 2., 0.],
         [0., 0., 2., 4.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 3.]])

np.array([ e[ki, :].sum(axis=0) for ki in k ])
```